Truncating GRanges Objects at a Specific Position in R
I am working with GRanges objects in R.
# example
gr <- GRanges(
  seqnames = Rle(c("chr1", 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr2')),
  ranges = IRanges(start = c(1, 3, 6, 19), end = c(6, 10, 10, 39)),
  strand = Rle(strand(c('+', '+', '-', '+'))),
  score = 1:4
)
GRanges object with 4 ranges and 1 metadata column:
      seqnames    ranges strand |     score
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
  [1]     chr1       1-6      + |         1
  [2]     chr1      3-10      + |         2
  [3]     chr1      6-10      - |         3
  [4]     chr2     19-39      + |         4

I want to truncate these objects at a given position.
chr <- 'chr1'
pos <- 9
gr_tunc <- function(x) {
## do someting

return(gr)
}
gr_new <- gr_tunc(gr)

expected output:
# keep upstream of speicifc position
# if region overlap with pos, tuncat it
# only keey same seqlevel
gr_new <- GRanges(
  seqnames = Rle(c("chr1", 'chr1', 'chr1')),
  ranges = IRanges(start = c(1, 3, 9), end = c(6, 9, 10)),
  strand = Rle(strand(c('+', '+', '-'))),
  score = 1:3
)
GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
      seqnames    ranges strand |     score
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
  [1]     chr1       1-6      + |         1
  [2]     chr1       3-9      + |         2
  [3]     chr1      9-10      - |         3

We have tried to achieve this goal by comparing GRanges objects line by line, but this method seems to be too inefficient.
